# Trying to auto add dates in multiple columns after autocheck boxes

Tags: excel, date, checkbox, autofill, vba

I am trying to help my mother out with a spreadsheet for her tshirt inventory so she will be able to have checkboxes and a date that fills in after checking the style. After numerous hours of videos and research on websites I tried to do a combination of these codes but without luck:

*(from website: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8-mso_2016/use-check-box-to-create-date-time-stamp/a466c68a-2440-4ce0-9a73-2abe73256a0b )*

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change() 
    Dim destSH As Worksheet 
    Dim rngDate As Range, rngTime As Range 
    Set destSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 
    With destSH Set rngDate = .Range("E2") 
         Set rngTime = .Range("D2") 
    End With 
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
    With rngDate .Value = Date 
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 
    End With 
    With rngTime .Value = Now() 
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm" 
    End With
    End If 
End Sub
```

---

and this website: *(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9e6dd210-59db-4018-a0c2-6a60dc03aeb8/check-box-that-insert-todays-date-in-another-cell?forum=exceldev)*

---

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim cel As Range
     If Not Intersect(Range("C2:C100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     For Each cel In Intersect(Range("C2:C100"), Target)
        If cel.Value = "" Then
            cel.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).ClearContents
        Else
            cel.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Date
        End If
        Next cel
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        End Sub
```

---

### This is the alteration I ended up with after trying to fix multiple errors -

```
        Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
        Dim destSH As Worksheet
        Dim rngDate As Range

        Set destSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")
        If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then

        With rngDate.Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        End With

        Set rngDate = Range("E2,E48")
        If Not Range("D2,D48") Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

         End If           
        Set rngDate = Range("G2,G48")
        If Not Range("F2,F48") Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

           End IF
         Set rngDate = Range("I2,I48")
           If Not Range("H2,H48") Is Nothing Then
         Application.EnableEvents = False

         End IF
      Set rngDate = Range("K2,K48")
      If Not Range("J2,J48") Is Nothing Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False

           End IF
      Set rngDate = Range("N2,N48")
      If Not Range("M2,M48") Is Nothing Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False

            End IF
     Set rngDate = Range("P2,P48")
     If Not Range("O2,O48") Is Nothing Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False

           End IF
     Set rngDate = Range("R2,R48")
     If Not Range("Q2,Q48") Is Nothing Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False

           End If
     Set rngDate = Range("T2,T48")
     If Not Range("S2,S48") Is Nothing Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False

    End If

End Sub
```

---

Current spreadsheet

[image: img]

I was also trying to set up the sum for each checked box in order for her to see how many items sold at the bottom.

When I set up the checked boxes they were all Active X and I am pretty sure I checked the true button but I can't figure out where to find the information now.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Thank you for your question SarahPick. Some remarks: Your code only operates on checkbox 1 I believe, however you have about a hunderd checkboxes. Also from your second source you did'nt keep the crucial part: `cel.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Date`which inserts the date into cells.

Comment: Thank you I will try to see what I can do to adjust that. Is there a way to allow all checkboxes to be included? I tried grouping them by shirt style, I've also named most columns. (I.E. D is MensS, E is MensSSold, etc. )